# Clearing the cache via API

Tags: add-on-development, extension, cache, caching, channel-entries-api

The Expression Engine documentation for caching explains that the caches are automatically cleared upon:

> Submission, updating or deleting of an Entry through API

I need to clear the caches via my own extension. Is it possible to tap into a function to clear the caches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ref: https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/legacy/libraries/cache.html#class-methods

ee()->cache->delete('/myaddon/');